# How to get meta_key from wp_postmeta?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I used this query for get posts by category name. It's working well. now i need to get sub_title from meta_key. Any one can help how to add wp_postmeta in this query.

```
`SELECT * 
FROM wp_terms
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wpr ON wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON p.ID = wpr.object_id
AND p.post_type =  'post'
AND p.post_status =  'publish'
AND name =  '$name'
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC`
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please Give more about your table structure meta_key?

Comment: I want to display sub_title. But subtitles are stored in wp_postmeta-->meta_key. I think need to add INNER JOIN.how to write?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add another INNER JOIN, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_terms
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy 
ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wpr 
ON wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_posts 
ON p.ID = wpr.object_id AND p.post_type =  'post' AND p.post_status =  'publish' AND name =  '$name'
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wpm 
ON p.ID = wpm.post_id AND wpm.meta_key = 'subtitle'
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```